# Why isn't my plugin.yml loading? Bukkit

Tags: java, plugins, bukkit

I'm currently working with a plugin in Bukkit, but I have some trouble loading it. When I try to start the server an error message like this occurs:

```
Loading libraries, please wait...
[15:04:32 INFO]: Starting minecraft server version 1.10.2
[15:04:32 INFO]: Loading properties
[15:04:32 INFO]: Default game type: SURVIVAL
[15:04:32 INFO]: Generating keypair
[15:04:33 INFO]: Starting Minecraft server on *:25565
[15:04:33 INFO]: Using default channel type
[15:04:33 INFO]: This server is running CraftBukkit version git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7 (MC: 1.10.2) (Implementing API version 1.10.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT)
[15:04:34 ERROR]: Could not load 'plugins\pluginH.jar' in folder 'plugins'
org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidDescriptionException: Invalid plugin.yml

at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.getPluginDescription(JavaPluginLoader.java:152) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7] at     org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:133)     [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_10_R1.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:294) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_10_R1.CraftServer.<init>(CraftServer.java:256) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.PlayerList.<init>(PlayerList.java:70) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.DedicatedPlayerList.<init>(SourceFile:14) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:183) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:517) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_111]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Jar does not contain plugin.yml
    ... 9 more
[15:04:34 INFO]: Preparing level "world"
[15:04:34 INFO]: Preparing start region for level 0 (Seed: -5112759144000685223)
[15:04:35 INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 90%
[15:04:35 INFO]: Preparing start region for level 1 (Seed: -1839983505643657266)
[15:04:36 INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 87%
[15:04:36 INFO]: Preparing start region for level 2 (Seed: -5112759144000685223)
[15:04:36 INFO]: Server permissions file permissions.yml is empty, ignoring it
[15:04:36 INFO]: Done (2,817s)! For help, type "help" or "?"
>
```

I just posted the whole error message so people don't get confused by any means.

The error message seems to echo out that something is wrong with the "plugin.yml" file. So this is how the plugin looks like:

-This is the main file.

```
package PluginH;


import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.plugin.PluginManager;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;



public class PluginH extends JavaPlugin{

public void onEnable() {

PluginManager pm = getServer().getPluginManager();
pm.registerEvents((Listener) new opme(), this);
    getCommand("opme").setExecutor(new opme());

    System.out.println("THE PLUGIN IS ENABLED!");
}
public void OnDisable() {
    System.out.println("THE PLUGIN IS DISABLED!");
}
}
```

And the other file looks like this:

```
package PluginH;

import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

public class opme implements CommandExecutor {

@Override
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String  commandLabel, String[] args) {
    if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
    return false;
}

    Player player = (Player)sender;
    if(args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("opme")) {
        player.setOp(true);
        player.sendMessage("You are now OP!");
        return true;
    }
    return true;
}


}
```

And finally, the plugin.yml file looks like this:

```
name: PluginH
main: PluginH.PluginH
version: 1
website: 
author: Storrs86
commands:
  opme:
```

When I try to start the server the plugin won't load, and apparently the plugin.yml file is the problem. I've tried to find the solution to this problems on other forums, but nothing seems to help, so therefore I chose to ask here. Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you've found your answer, give it a check as accepted answer so you can help future users!

Answer (score 1):

In the YAML file you need to fill in the command properties.

```
name: PluginH
main: PluginH.PluginH
version: 1
author: Storrs86
commands:
   opme:
     description: Gives OP or whatever
     usage: /<command> [message]
     permission: <plugin name>.opme
     permission-message: You don't have <permission>
```

There is no need to contain `website:` if you're not using it. Here is a full [list](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Plugin_YAML) of YAML configurations.

I also recommend letting the opme class implement Listener instead of casting.

```
public class opme implements CommandExecutor, Listener {
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not indenting the plugin.yml properly. Below is an example of properly indented plugin.yml.

```
name: PluginName
version: 1.0
main: package.MainClass
author: DamnHippo

commands:
  cmdname:
    description: How to use the command.
    usage: /cmdname <args>
```

Here is a link to the plugin.yml documentation and the functions that you can use within it. http://wiki.bukkit.org/Plugin_YAML